# C - Pointer to array of strings not working

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I'm trying to make pointer to array of strings to iterate through it.
I have array defined like that:

```
const char **Argument_ACTIONS={
"default",
"store_true",
"store_false",
"show_help",
"show_version",
NULL
};
```

And in the function I have that piece of code:

```
char **ptr=&Argument_ACTIONS;
printf("%s\n",*ptr);
ptr++;
printf("%s\n",*ptr);
```

Expected output was:

> default
>
> store_true

but I got:

> default

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Turn your compiler warnings on.

Comment: Sorry I forgot, I got: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
But I don't know what I must change.

Comment: This char **ptr=&Argument_ACTIONS

Comment: That I know, but what change in that line?
Pointer is defined wrong or something else?

Comment: remove `&` as `&Argument_ACTIONS` is `char ***`

Comment: char **ptr=Argument_ACTIONS;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is defined incorrectly, it should've been:

```
const char *Argument_ACTIONS[] = { // <-- notice [] which defines an array
    "default",
    "store_true",
    "store_false",
    "show_help",
    "show_version",
    NULL
};
```

In your case however you defined a double pointer and assigned it a list of single pointers. This doesn't really make sense but C compiler allows it with a few warnings. It essentially implicitly casts the first string from `const char *` to `const char **` and discards the rest:

```
main.c:2:1: warning: initialization of ‘const char **’ from incompatible pointer type ‘char *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
 "default",
 ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:2:1: note: (near initialization for ‘Argument_ACTIONS’)
main.c:3:1: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 "store_true",
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:3:1: note: (near initialization for ‘Argument_ACTIONS’)
main.c:4:1: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 "store_false",
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:4:1: note: (near initialization for ‘Argument_ACTIONS’)
main.c:5:1: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 "show_help",
 ^~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:5:1: note: (near initialization for ‘Argument_ACTIONS’)
main.c:6:1: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
 "show_version",
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.c:6:1: note: (near initialization for ‘Argument_ACTIONS’)
```

You should change your `ptr` to:

```
const char **ptr = Argument_ACTIONS;
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm understand what I done wrong before.